# How to see the UID of all files or folders

Tags: users

When I do a `ls -al`, I can see the owner and group of files or folders. However, I recently changed my UID, so how do I find out if all my folders belong to my username **and** the new uid?

Comment: I am not sure about the question. Are you meaning that you want to find all the files with your old UID and changing their ownership to the new one?

Answer (score 101):

Well, If you meant that you want to see the UIDs of the file then `ls` command can help.

You can use `ls` with *n* flag.

```
    ls -n
```

`-n` explanation from man page :

```
-n, --numeric-uid-gid
              like -l, but list numeric user and group IDs.
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Well, linux tracks ownership by uid only so

```
find / -uid 1000
```

Change the uid 1000 to the uid you wish to search on.

Comment: It found loads and said permission denied.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a process in Ubuntu to create the first user account with a specific UID. If you want to use a non-default UID, it appears you have to break everything in your system by changing the UID & then try and fix parts of it when you find the problems. It's really terrible & I'm absolutely lost as to what has to change and where everything that needs to change is located.

Comment: No, you have to change the uid properly, best from a live usb. You can probably select a uid using the advanced options in the installer. See also https://muffinresearch.co.uk/linux-changing-uids-and-gids-for-user/ . But yes, is you go changing things , especially system settings, without understanding how, you will break ubuntu.

Comment: What I normally do is install the system creating an administrative user (say "defaultadm") and then from there I create, using `adduser`, my user which has a different, special UID (you know, in 1992 we had a personal UID to share file with NFS that had no UID tables then, and I got sentimental with it :-)). This way is clean and you'll have no problem whatsoever. Trying to change an UID all over the system is almost impossible --- it's not just file ownership, it's **into** some file too --- think `/etc/groups`.

Answer (score 1):

`$ ls -lnR yourdir`

- In case information is needed of a directory

Answer (score 1):

For checking the **uid:gid** of a directory owner:group

```
$ ls -nd /path/to/directory
```